# Convert HTML to Javascript String

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, single-page-application

I'm reading a book on how to create a SPA (single page applications). The author writes, if the IDE is any good then there will be a technique to convert a highlighted section of HTML and converted to a JavaScript string. How can this be done in Visual Studio 2013? An example of how I want the convert to work is below. Also it would be great to toggle back to the html.

HTML

```
<div class="spa-shell-head">
 <div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>
 <div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>
 <div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var main_html = String()
+ '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
 + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
 + '<div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>'
 + '<div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>'
+ '</div>';
```

Comment: If the programmer is any good then (s)he would never put HTML strings into the code in any form.

Comment: Paul did you find a solution?

@Derek instead of just saying "don't do it", can't you come with something more useful? From my understanding "appending" and similar functions are used quite a lot to add html to places where it wasn't earlier, now that html needs to come from somewhere, so if not from a string, where then?

Comment: @Logan I've added an answer that explains all that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting HTML to a JS string, it would be much better to create the elements in JS and put them in the DOM. This would give you much more control, not create such a difficult to maintain/read code, create less problems, and be much faster:

```
var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
outerDiv.className = "spa-shell-head";

var innerDivLogo = document.createElement("div");
innerDivLogo.className = "spa-shell-head-logo";

var innerDivAcct = document.createElement("div");
innerDivAcct.className = "spa-shell-head-acct";

var innerDivSearch = document.createElement("div");
innerDivSearch.className = "spa-shell-head-search";

outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivLogo);
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivAcct);
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivSearch);
document.body.appendChild(outerDiv);
```

The above creates the following:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yfeLbhe4/